# Mount physical disk with swap included

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, swap

I'm using VirtualBox and a virtual hard disk, formatted as a swap partition, for booting a virtual machine with a USB key. The guest machine is Ubuntu 10.04. I realized that there's no swap partition on the USB key.

Is there a way to mount the swap on the virtual disk automatically without affecting when I boot the USB key drive on real hardware?

Answer (score 1):

The `nofail` mount option for swap partitions will cause `swapon` to ignore the partition if it doesn't exist.